# How to get cpio (gnu, rhel 4) to extract to a specified directory?

Tags: linux, redhat

Reason is I want to make a tidy script instead of

```
cd /some/dir
cpio -whatever<somefile
cd -
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing in GNU cpio to allow for this.  This might be a little cleaner:

```
(cd /some/dir && cpio -whatever < /some/file)
```

Using the subshell parentheses will preserve the scripts current working directory and using && will ensure that the cpio extraction is only done if you successfully change directories to the target.

Comment: The `somefile` has to actually reside in `/some/dir` here. I just tried it and it sayd it couldn't find the files. So you either have to use relative paths back to where the files were or absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a little more to what TCampbell did:

(cp /some/file /some/dir && cd /some/dir && cpio -whatever < file && rm -f file)

Answer (score 0):

Use `-D` option (`cpio (GNU cpio) 2.13`, should be available in most modern distributions):

```
OPTIONS
   Operation modifiers valid in any mode
       -D, --directory=DIR
              Change to directory DIR.
```

```shell
cat archive | cpio -D /tmp/outdir -idmv
```

Output directory will be created, if it doesn't exist.